# Geowebcache is does not seed from rest and web UI

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, curl

I am trying CURL to seed geowebcache:

```
curl -v -u USERNAME:PASSWORD -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<seedRequest><name>WORKSPACE:LAYER</name><srs><number>4326</number></srs><zoomStart>1</zoomStart><zoomStop>12</zoomStop><format>image/png</format><type>truncate</type><threadCount>2</threadCount></seedRequest>" "http://127.0.0.1:8090/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed/WORKSPACE:LAYER.xml"
```

this works like this: 
[image]

But this command deletind all tiles cached via GWC demo page.

I tried **seed type** like this.

```
curl -v -u USERNAME:PASSWORD -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<seedRequest><name>WORKSPACE:LAYER</name><srs><number>4326</number></srs><zoomStart>1</zoomStart><zoomStop>12</zoomStop><format>image/png</format><type>seed</type><threadCount>2</threadCount></seedRequest>" "http://127.0.0.1:8090/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed/WORKSPACE:LAYER.xml"
```

But no tile is creating on server. Disk quota is 0MB.

I am trying to create seed task from wen UI but not working.

Demo gwc page is working and creating tiles. And openlayers application is creting tiles.

But I caould not create qutomatically seed and create tiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using geoserver built in geowebcache, this issue cen be occured. I recommand you that install a standalone geowebcacbe. Standalone installation is working fine.